# Android instagram page in webview infinitely loads

Tags: android, facebook, redirect, webview, instagram

I'm using android `WebView` to load Instagram login page. It loads fine and I can see it on the screen. After that I click on "Login via Facebook" button which redirects me to Facebook login page. I enter my Facebook credentials and click login button. After that Facebook redirects me back to Instagram to redirect URI (which is https://www.instagram.com/accounts/signup) and this page loads infinitely (if I do the same operations in browser, Facebook redirects me to the same page but this page doesn't load infinitely, but redirects me to my Instagram account's profile page instead). What can I do to prevent infinitely loading? Here's my code of `Activity` with `WebView` and a screenshot of screen with this page

```
public class InstagramAuthActivity extends BaseActivity implements InstagramRepository.OnLoadListener<String> {

    public static final String EXTRA_COOKIES = "cookies_instagram";
    public static final String EXTRA_USERNAME = "username_instagram";

    private static final String URL = "https://www.instagram.com";

    private ViewHolder mViewHolder;
    private String mCookies;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_instagram_auth);
        createViewHolder();
        populateViewHolder();
    }

    private void createViewHolder() {
        mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        mViewHolder.mAuthWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.auth);
    }

    private void populateViewHolder() {
        WebSettings settings = mViewHolder.mAuthWebView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mViewHolder.mAuthWebView.setWebViewClient(new InstagramWebViewClient());
        mViewHolder.mAuthWebView.loadUrl(URL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoad(String data) {
        if (data != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_COOKIES, mCookies);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_USERNAME, data);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        } else {
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        }
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFail() {
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        finish();
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        WebView mAuthWebView;
    }

    private class InstagramWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            Log.d("tag", "url: " + url + "; cookies: " + cookies);
            if (cookies.contains("ds_user_id")) {
                mCookies = cookies;
                String[] cookieData = cookies.split("; ");
                if (cookieData != null && cookieData.length > 1) {
                    String[] idData = null;
                    for (String cookie : cookieData) {
                        if (cookie.contains("ds_user_id")) {
                            idData = cookie.split("=");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (idData != null && idData.length > 1) {
                        InstagramRepository.getInstance(InstagramAuthActivity.this).getUsername(idData[1], InstagramAuthActivity.this);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's also logs with all URLs to which I redirected

```
09-14 10:53:14.555 21316-21316/ru.luckybook D/tag: url: https://www.instagram.com/
09-14 10:53:15.539 21316-21316/ru.luckybook D/tag: url: https://www.instagram.com/
09-14 10:53:22.048 21316-21316/ru.luckybook D/tag: url: https://m.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=124024574287414&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fv1.0%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.instagram.com%252Faccounts%252Fsignup%252F%26scope%3Demail%26response_type%3Dtoken%252Cgranted_scopes%26client_id%3D124024574287414%26ret%3Dlogin%26logger_id%3D7b5f7abf-6769-464a-86e9-a26e8301375d&cancel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.instagram.com%2Faccounts%2Fsignup%2F%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%23_%3D_&display=touch&locale=ru_RU&logger_id=7b5f7abf-6769-464a-86e9-a26e8301375d&_rdr
09-14 10:53:46.864 21316-21316/ru.luckybook D/tag: url: https://www.instagram.com/accounts/signup/
```

[image: This page loads infinitely]

Comment: override `onPageFinished` method and check whether it is called or not

Comment: I've done it. onPageFinished called and I've printed url in logs. It is https://www.instagram.com/accounts/signup Same as in browser. But in browser I'm redirected from this page to profile page, but in WebView this page doesn't do anything. It just shows progress bar.

Comment: I think there is some problem with your url. For me it is redirecting to facebook login. Put logs in error method and check there.

Comment: @VivekMishra I've added my logs with all URLs in post

Comment: you have to log error not url

Comment: @VivekMishra I've printed all logs from onPageFinished and onReceivedError methods. As we can see, there's no onReceivedError method calls

Comment: @OlegRyabtsev Did you find any solution? For me the work around is to use AdvanceWebview lib, after using that lib, instagram loads without a hitch. But still i am wondering why the stock webview has issues with it?

Comment: @Michal_196 unfortunately, didn't. I had to hide facebook login button through javascript injection. I will try your solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you create your `WebView`, you just have to enable third party cookies in your `WebView` like this:

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView,true);
```

After this, Instagram will start working fine in your `WebView`. I had the same issue and I have solved it by implementing the above mentioned code.

Answer (score -1):

I have found a solution, hopefully it will help others.

The Following block is important,

```
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);  

private void populateViewHolder() {
    WebSettings settings = mViewHolder.mAuthWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mViewHolder.mAuthWebView.setWebViewClient(new InstagramWebViewClient());
    mViewHolder.mAuthWebView.loadUrl(URL);    
}
```

After Enabling this option, Instagram working fine.

I think it is `disabled by default for space savings and security`.